# Repository pattern in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I'm working on a prototype to use a document database (currently MongoDB, may change) and found the .NET drivers a bit of a pain, so I thought I would abstract the data access with the Repository pattern. This should make it easy to swap out whatever driver I'm using now (NoRM, mongodb-csharp, simple-mongob) with *your killer f# mongodb driver that doesn't suck* when it's ready.

My question is around the *Add* operation. This is going to have some side affect to the database and thus subsequent calls to *All* will be different. Should I care? In C# traditionally I wouldn't, but I feel that in F# I should.

Here is the generic repository interface:

```
type IRepository<'a> =
    interface
        abstract member All : unit -> seq<'a>

        // Add has a side-effect of modifying the database
        abstract member Add : 'a -> unit
    end
```

And here is how a MongoDB implementation looks:

```
type Repository<'b when 'b : not struct>(server:MongoDB.IMongo,database) =
    interface IRepository<'b> with

        member x.All() =
            // connect and return all

        member x.Add(document:'b) =
            // add and return unit
```

Throughout the app I will use IRepository, making it easy to change drivers and potentially databases.

Calling All is fine, but with Add what I was hoping was instead of returning unit, return a new repository instance. Something like:

```
        // Add has a side-effect of modifying the database
        // but who cares as we now return a new repository
        abstract member Add : 'a -> IRepository<'a>
```

The problem is that if I call Get, then Add, the original repository still returns all the documents. Example:

```
let repo1 = new Repository<Question>(server,"killerapp") :> IRepository<Question>
let a1 = repo1.All() 
let repo2 = repo1.Add(new Question("Repository pattern in F#"))
let a2 = repo2.All()
```

Ideally I want length of a1 and a2 to be different, but they are the same as they both hit the database. The application works, users can ask their question, but the programmer is left wondering why it returns a new IRepository.

So should I be trying to handle the side-effect from Add on the database in the design of the types? How would others go about this, do you use a Repository or some interface class like this or have some better functional approach?

Comment: What you're talking about, MongoDB does not support, but the idea is still interesting, and at least one implementation exists. Take a look at http://www.datomic.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're applying immutability to functions that affect state in the outside world. Regardless of the F# implementation, how would you see this working at the MongoDB level? How would you prevent `repo1` from seeing any changes that `repo2` makes? What happens if some other process affects the database -- do both `repo1` and `repo2` change in this case?

To put it another way, imagine an implementation of `System.Console` that worked like this. If `Console.Out.WriteLine` always returned a new immutable object, how would it interact with calls to `Console.In.ReadLine`?

**Edit tl;dr:** Don't do this. Sometimes side effects are fine.

Comment: +1 I agree with Tim. In short: no, returning a new IRepository in Add does not make sense here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it makes sense to have an immutable interface to an innately mutable type (such as a database).  However, you might want to split the functionality into a mutable database type (`IRepository<'a>` in your case) and an immutable set of changes (such as `ChangeSet<'a>`, for example).  The result might look something like:

```
type ChangeSet<'a> = ...                         //'
module ChangeSet = begin                         //'
  let empty = ...                                //'
  let add a c = ...                              //'
  ...
end

type IRepository<'a> =                           //'
  abstract GetAll : unit -> seq<'a>              //'
  abstract ApplyChanges : ChangeSet<'a> -> unit  //'

type Repository<'a> = ...                        //'

let repo = new Repository<Question>(...)
let changes =
  ChangeSet.empty
  |> ChangeSet.add (Question "Repository pattern in F#")
  |> ChangeSet.add (Question "...")
repo.ApplyChanges changes
let results = repo.GetAll()
```

Comment: Here a `Repository` represents the database's transaction log at a point in time, and `ChangeSet` represents a transaction. This is very cool, but I have no idea how it would map to some underlying database server.

Comment: Interesting, is this ChangeSet and ApplyChanges the Unit of Work pattern?

Comment: @yanta - yes, essentially.  The pattern is typically presented with a mutable unit of work, but there's no reason that it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a computational expression to make it seem pure. You could even extend it further with code to handle timeouts and downed servers. I am new to the concept so if the experts could school me if something seems inappropriate.

I think this concept would be much more useful if you were threading through more than just a repository but I wanted to keep it simple.

```
type IRepository<'a> = //'                                             
    abstract member All : unit -> seq<'a> //' 
    abstract member Add : 'a -> unit //' 
    abstract member Get : int -> 'a //' 

type Rep<'a, 'b> = IRepository<'a> -> 'b //' 

type RepositoryBuilder() =
    member x.Bind (f:Rep<'a, 'b>, g:'b -> Rep<'a, 'c>) rep = g (f rep) rep //'            
    member x.Delay (f:unit -> Rep<'a, 'b>) = f () //' 
    member x.Return v r = v
    member x.ReturnFrom f = f
    member x.Zero () = () 

let rep = RepositoryBuilder()   

let action (action:_->unit) repository = 
    action repository    

let func (func:Rep<_, _>) repository = 
    func repository   

type Person = {
    id:int
    name:string
    age:int
    finalized:bool
}

let addPeople = rep {
    do! action(fun r -> r.Add { id = 1; name = "Jim"; age = 45; finalized = false })
    do! action(fun r -> r.Add { id = 2; name = "Bob"; age = 32; finalized = false })
    do! action(fun r -> r.Add { id = 3; name = "Sue"; age = 58; finalized = false })
    do! action(fun r -> r.Add { id = 5; name = "Matt"; age = 11; finalized = false }) 
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest I don't follow this, but I will have a look into computational expressions and hopefully I can come back to this.

Comment: @yanta - If you can pinpoint what is particularly confusing I can try and elaborate.

Comment: I dont understand the RepositoryBuilder, what are all those members like Bind for and where are they used? Then the let addPeople = rep {...} is this actually executed on the repository straight away?